# How, and in which cases does glDrawArrays modify vertex attributes?

Tags: opengl

From the documentation of [glDrawArrays](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml):

> Vertex attributes that are modified by glDrawArrays have an
> unspecified value after glDrawArrays returns. Attributes that aren't
> modified remain well defined.

I understand that glDrawArrays uses buffer data and some information about how to interpret the data as vertices in order to draw graphics. What I don't understand is how this can result in modifiying vertex attributes.

I am seeing some strange values in my vertex buffer data, after I map it with `glMapBufferRange`, and I'm trying to track down where the unexpected values could be originating from.